# Does _spawn_posix in distutils always raise an error?

Tags: python, distutils, python-os

I'm afraid to send this to the `distutils` mailing list, because I'm pretty sure I'm making a dumb misinterpretation.

Here is the function `_spawn_posix` in `distutils` version 2.7.9:

```
def _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path=1, verbose=0, dry_run=0):
    log.info(' '.join(cmd))
    if dry_run:
        return
    executable = cmd[0]
    exec_fn = search_path and os.execvp or os.execv
    env = None
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        global _cfg_target, _cfg_target_split
        if _cfg_target is None:
            _cfg_target = sysconfig.get_config_var(
                                  'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET') or ''
            if _cfg_target:
                _cfg_target_split = [int(x) for x in _cfg_target.split('.')]
        if _cfg_target:
            # ensure that the deployment target of build process is not less
            # than that used when the interpreter was built. This ensures
            # extension modules are built with correct compatibility values
            cur_target = os.environ.get('MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET', _cfg_target)
            if _cfg_target_split > [int(x) for x in cur_target.split('.')]:
                my_msg = ('$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: '
                          'now "%s" but "%s" during configure'
                                % (cur_target, _cfg_target))
                raise DistutilsPlatformError(my_msg)
            env = dict(os.environ,
                       MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=cur_target)
            exec_fn = search_path and os.execvpe or os.execve
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:  # in the child
        try:
            if env is None:
                exec_fn(executable, cmd)
            else:
                exec_fn(executable, cmd, env)
        except OSError, e:
            if not DEBUG:
                cmd = executable
            sys.stderr.write("unable to execute %r: %s\n" %
                             (cmd, e.strerror))
            os._exit(1)

        if not DEBUG:
            cmd = executable
        sys.stderr.write("unable to execute %r for unknown reasons" % cmd)
        os._exit(1)
    else:   # in the parent
        # Loop until the child either exits or is terminated by a signal
        # (ie. keep waiting if it's merely stopped)
        while 1:
            try:
                pid, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
            except OSError, exc:
                import errno
                if exc.errno == errno.EINTR:
                    continue
                if not DEBUG:
                    cmd = executable
                raise DistutilsExecError, \
                      "command %r failed: %s" % (cmd, exc[-1])
            if os.WIFSIGNALED(status):
                if not DEBUG:
                    cmd = executable
                raise DistutilsExecError, \
                      "command %r terminated by signal %d" % \
                      (cmd, os.WTERMSIG(status))

            elif os.WIFEXITED(status):
                exit_status = os.WEXITSTATUS(status)
                if exit_status == 0:
                    return   # hey, it succeeded!
                else:
                    if not DEBUG:
                        cmd = executable
                    raise DistutilsExecError, \
                          "command %r failed with exit status %d" % \
                          (cmd, exit_status)

            elif os.WIFSTOPPED(status):
                continue

            else:
                if not DEBUG:
                    cmd = executable
                raise DistutilsExecError, \
                      "unknown error executing %r: termination status %d" % \
                      (cmd, status)
```

Obviously there's a lot there.  No one wants to read that.  All you need to do is the following:

- Find the line `exec_fn(executable, cmd)`.  That's the line this whole function is setup to execute.  It calls `os.execvp`.
- Notice that `exec_fn` is only called when `pid == 0`.
- Notice that when `pid == 0`, the following code is called:

  ```
      try:
          if env is None:
              exec_fn(executable, cmd)
          else:
              exec_fn(executable, cmd, env)
      except OSError, e:
          if not DEBUG:
              cmd = executable
          sys.stderr.write("unable to execute %r: %s\n" %
                           (cmd, e.strerror))
          os._exit(1)

      if not DEBUG:
          cmd = executable
      sys.stderr.write("unable to execute %r for unknown reasons" % cmd)
      os._exit(1)
  ```
- Notice here that if an `OSError` is raised in the `try` block, we exit to the system with a status of 1 (failure).
- Notice that even if an `OSError` is *not* raised, we *still* exit to the system with a status of 1 (failure).
- In both cases, the parent process, which has been waiting for the child to finish, raises a `DistutilsExecError`.

Can someone point out my error?  Or do I happen to be using the version of `distutils` with a crazy bug that has since been fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, OK, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) say about `os.execvp` and the other `os.exec` functions

> These functions all execute a new program, **replacing the current process**; they do not return. **On Unix, the new executable is loaded into the current process**, and will have the same process id as the caller. Errors will be reported as OSError exceptions.

So once the call to `exec_fn` is made, if it's successful, the lines that follow are never executed.  They have been replaced by the new `os.execvp` process.